# Delphi TBitBtn white layer

Tags: delphi

How can I get rid of the white layer drawn under the bitmap images by Delphi/Windows when Glyph property of TBitBtn is used. I just want to draw the image, no shadow under it, no other layers that comes automatically. I am inserting round shaped 24 bit bitmap images.

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/90617947@N04/8230222478/in/photostream]

Comment: The question lacks essential information. You didn't show how this white later comes about. Unless you give us enough information to get on the same page as you, how can we help?

Comment: Sounds like ignored transparency of the glyph. (But 24-bit bitmap images have no alpha channel.)

Comment: the left bottom pixel is used for definition of the "transparent" color.

Comment: I've inserted a link to a screenshot. I'll look into the transparency issue. I was hoping for a simple setting or property to get rid of that layer.

Comment: Why aren't you using an alpha channel?

Comment: By the way, since that's a standard image, you can simple load it with LoadImage. No need to include it in your app. Do that and your app will use the platform native glyph no matter what OS it runs on.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've actually created a resource file, and created a custom component that inherits the TBitBtn. Component reads from the resource and doesn't write into DFM. We'll be able to load these images during design time in the future and also replace existing code with a simple copy paste. There are hundreds of buttons that needs to be replaced. Goal is to use high quality images rather than the standard ones. We're on XE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have a 24-bit bitmap, there is no alpha transparency, so Delphi uses the bottom left pixel of the image to determine the transparent color. All pixels with that color are treated as transparent. The part of the image with the shadow effect is not an exact match for the designated transparent color, so those pixels are painted normally, just like the rest of the image.

The shadow appears white because there was a white background in the graphic program when your designer applied the shadow effect.

Either edit the image to remove the shadow, or use a 32-bit image with alpha transparency. You'll be hard-pressed to apply alpha transparency after the fact. Fix the source image.

Comment: Changing the bottom left pixel color didn't help out much. Didn't dig into it too much though. However, editing out the image file on an image editor worked for me. Those who are curious about the details; I didn't originally created these images so I've created a transparent PNG image, copied the BMP file into it, than with the Wand Tool (pixlr.com) selected and deleted the white background. Saved image as BMP, and there's no more that white layer showing on my button. Thanks!

Comment: Changing the transparent-color pixel wouldn't help anyway. The shadow is made up of *many* shades of white and gray. No *single* color is going to make all of them transparent.